# How to initialize value in flutter? It says late initialization error

Tags: flutter, dart

I ran a project in flutter it says in the analyzer in the first case and in the emulator in the second case late initialization error I didn't know how to solve this problem.

***First case***

```dart
List<Student>? studentsList
```

It made an error in the analyzer.

***Second case***

```dart
late List<Student> studentsList
```

it ran and didn't make an error in the analyzer but it made a red screen in the emulator and said late initialization error.
how to initialize it?

Comment: it depends on where & how you;ve assigning the value, providing default value or making nullable I will prefer.

Answer (score 3):

To understand it better, let me explain in simple terms.

**First Case**

```
List<Student>? studentsList
```

You are saying compiler `studentsList` can be potentially `null`. So you can access it like.

```
if (studentsList != null) {
  // do something with studentsList
}
```

or Using `null aware` `?` operator.

```
studentsList?.add(Student());
```

---

**Second Case**

```
late List<Student> studentsList;
```

You are saying compiler , I will make sure I will initialize `studentsList` before I use it. So if you dont obey the promise `compiler` will throw `LaterInitializationError`.

You can overcome this by initializing before use like:

```
late List<Student> studentsList = [];
```

or you can intialize somewhere in the `initState`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your object before you want to use it.

Way 1:

```
List<Student> studentList = [];
```

in this case you are initializing your `studentList` object with empty list and you can re initialize it because its not final.

Way 2:

If you want to make your list final so that you can not reinitialize it, then do like this.

```
final List<Student> studentList = [];
```

in this case you perform add, remove and others list functionalities without any problem but you can not re initialize it again.

I can say you do not need `late` keyword to define your student list anymore.

After all if you really want to use `late` keyword like this

```
late List<Student> studentList;
```

then make sure you have initialized your list like bellow and remember one thing you can not re initialize the `studentList` once you initialize it otherwise you will get late init error.

```
studentList = []; // or studentList = otherList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give it an empty list a initial value:

```
List<Student>? studentsList = [];
```

You should check out the dart basics

https://dart.dev/tutorials

Comment: we can't do it for all types, also it is somehow against `late` keyword intent.

Comment: What do you mean with we can't do it for all types? Can you give me an example? In my example i don't use the late example since i don't see his full code, i just initialized it with an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The `late` keyword uses when you want to postpone variable instantiation, I think a good way is to create an initializer method and call it just before the first usage like this:

```dart
late List<Student> studentsList;

// Initialize studentsList somewhere in your code, just before the first usage.
void initializeStudentsList() {
  studentsList = []; // Or fill it with desired data.
}
```